# From mayavi import mlab error

Tags: python, multithreading, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I am new to using *python* and have had some trouble getting the *mlab module* within mayavi to work.  In my script I can import mayavi just fine, but when I include the line:
from mayavi import mlab

it produces the **error**:

> Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread Abort trap: 6

I have spent a few hours trying to fix this error, but have come up empty handed.  Does anyone know why this line specifically crashes?  I can import other modules just fine, but the mlab one doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far

Comment: I've installed all mayavi dependencies using macports, checked that the correct version of python is being used (I have multiple installed), and have tried uninstalling python and reinstalling but none of those suggestions that  I found seemed to work.

Comment: try to import it as `import mayavi.mlab` and then call it in code in the same way

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!  Just wondering, what is the difference between the two methods?  I saw a bunch of stuff online that used the method I originally did without getting the errors.

Comment: Have the same problem! Didn't work for me... Installed `mayavi` with `conda`. If there is any update on this issue?